# php create friendly url

Tags: php, jquery, url, routes

I have a page with some links that I built which calls a webservice.

This is an extract of jquery function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'json.php',

    success: function (response) {
        data = response.obj;
        var errorCode = response.errorCode;
        if (errorCode === 200) {
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                l_id_nation = value.id;

                var name = value.name;
                var continente = name.val;

                $('#sidemenu').append('<li><a class="id_continent"  href="javascript:void(0)">' + continente + '</a></li>');

            });

            $('.id_continent').click(function () {
                var id_continent = $(this).html();
            });
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

On click, I open a page that shows some information. 
The url of the page is `/trip.php?id_trip=1234&continet=oceania`

I would like have a url like `/trip/123/oceania`

I'm thinking of creating a route file, but I don't understand how to create this new url dynamically.

Comment: the ajax function would appear to be independent of the desired url structure - or is the`"url of the page"` that you refer to the href of the link you generate in the ajax - sorry, it's a bit unclear

Comment: You need process generated url in your service api before you response to client. This way make your url is synchronized with clients and server. And you only manager everything in your server

Comment: You should return a friendly url in your json.php and use it in your javascript client's app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have interpreted correctly (?) you wish to convert the urls you harvest from the "webservice" call and convert them to seo friendly links?

The following is not jQuery but seems to parse the data and return the url in the format you want.

```
if( typeof( 'getPairs' )!='function' ){
    function getPairs(d,z) {
        var a = new Object();
        var pr = d.split(z);
        for( var i=0;i<pr.length;i++ ) {
                var p = pr[i].indexOf('=');
                if (p == -1) continue;
                var n = pr[i].substring(0,p);
                var v = pr[i].substring(p+1);
                a[n] = unescape(v);
        }
        return a;
    }
}
if( typeof( 'prepareurl' )!='function' ){
    function prepareurl(u){
        var p=u.split('?')[0].split('.')[0];
        var q=u.split('?')[1];
        var t=[p];
        var o=getPairs( q, '&' );
        for( k in o )t.push( o[k] );
        return t.join('/');
    }
}

alert( prepareurl( '/trip.php?id_trip=1234&continent=oceania' ) );

will return `/trip/1234/oceania`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how relevant this would be to your setup, but I'd suggest using a great microframework, Slim, which would not only help with your dynamic routes but also help you manage your webservices with much more ease. 
Setting up Slim is quite simple, read the docs here: http://www.slimframework.com/

Using Slim you can do something like this, the url which you are pointing to, /trip.php?id_trip=1234&continet=oceania can be specified in a route like this,

```
$app->get('/trip/{trip_id}/{continent}', function($request, $response, $args){
   $trip_d = $args['trip_id'];
   $continent = $args['continent']
   //Do something
});
```

Simple as that, any GET request matching the above route will hit this controller, and you can do your stuff in the method, moreover Slim also has built in support for Twig templating system which happens to be a great resource to manage your Views.

If you want to setup dynamic routes without any framework, you will have to use rewrite rules in the .htaccess file, you can find some useful info here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049
I'd suggest using a microframework instead of re-inventing the whole thing, Hope this helps.